# how to change nil into " " in array

Tags: ruby

```
#ask user for string input
puts "Enter Text"
# text user has entered
text = "Test text"
#put text into a array - "split" by just words and spaces
words = text.downcase.split('')
#array of letters a to z in array 
a_z = ('a'..'z').to_a 

#idealy - take each letter in text string and match them to a_z's index from 0-25 
#space values in text are replaced in array with " " instead of nil

words.map { |x| a_z.index(x) }
```

I am trying to take text, split text, turn text into a number based on a to z index ... shift that number and recombine and turn back into text...

the problem I am encountering now is that spaces in my text array show up as nil since their is no numerical value for nil in the a-z index.

how can I replace nil with " " so that my array can for example look like this:

```
#=> [1,2," "]
```

instead of:

```
#=> [1,2,nil]
```

Comment: Your input and output don't match. It's also confusing that the variable holding the characters is called `words`.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve here, but you could also consider using `split(" ")` - i.e. get an array of words, rather than an array of letters. (This seems more appropriate, given that you've used the variable name `words`!)

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
def shift_and_remove(str, shift)
  h = make_hash 'a'..'z', shift
  h.default_proc = ->(h,k) {' '}
  str.gsub(/./,h)
end

def make_hash(r, shift)
  base = r.first.ord
  r.each_with_object({}) { |c,h| h[c] = (base + (c.ord-base+shift) % 26).chr }
end
```

**Examples**

```
str = "Now is the time for 007 to appear!"
shift_and_remove(str, 0)  #=> " ow is the time for     to appear " 
shift_and_remove(str, 1)  #=> " px jt uif ujnf gps     up bqqfbs " 
shift_and_remove(str, 4)  #=> " sa mw xli xmqi jsv     xs ettiev " 
shift_and_remove(str, -1) #=> " nv hr sgd shld enq     sn zoodzq " 
shift_and_remove(str, -2) #=> " mu gq rfc rgkc dmp     rm ynncyp "
```

Notice that in all cases "N" has been converted to a space, "w" of "Now" has been shifted to "a" in the third example and "a" of "appear" has been shifted to "z" and "y", respectively, in the last two examples.

**Explanation**

When `shift #=> 2`, the hash is as follows:

```
h[c] = ('a'.ord + (c.ord-'a'.ord+shift) % 26).chr }
  #=> {"a"=>"c", "b"=>"d", "c"=>"e", "d"=>"f", "e"=>"g", "f"=>"h", "g"=>"i",
  #    "h"=>"j", "i"=>"k", "j"=>"l", "k"=>"m", "l"=>"n", "m"=>"o", "n"=>"p",
  #    "o"=>"q", "p"=>"r", "q"=>"s", "r"=>"t", "s"=>"u", "t"=>"v", "u"=>"w",
  #    "v"=>"x", "w"=>"y", "x"=>"z", "y"=>"a", "z"=>"b"}
```

All letters "a" to "x" are mapped to the next letter, whereas "y" and "z" are mapped to "a" and "b" respectively. Similarly, when `shift #=> -1`, "a" is mapped to "z" and all other letters are mapped to the preceding letter.

This uses the form of [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that employs a hash to determine the replacement of each character in the string (`/./`). The method [Hash#default_proc=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D) creates a proc that gives the value of `h[k]` when the hash `h` does not have a key `k`, namely a space.

**Capital letters**

If any capital letters present are to be shifted to capital letters (rather than converted to spaces), only a slight modification is required.

```
def shift_and_remove(str, shift)
  h = make_hash('a'..'z', shift).merge make_hash('A'..'Z', shift)
  h.default_proc = ->(h,k) {' '}
  str.gsub(/./,h)
end

shift_and_remove(str, 0)  #=> "Now is the time for     to appear " 
shift_and_remove(str, 1)  #=> "Opx jt uif ujnf gps     up bqqfbs " 
shift_and_remove(str, 4)  #=> "Rsa mw xli xmqi jsv     xs ettiev " 
shift_and_remove(str, -1) #=> "Mnv hr sgd shld enq     sn zoodzq " 
shift_and_remove(str, -2) #=> "Lmu gq rfc rgkc dmp     rm ynncyp "
```

Comment: Thanks I'll take some time to study this code! this is exactly what I was attempting to do.

Comment: OLadi, I'm glad you found this helpful. Note that I just made a few changes.